# get rid of numbering of figures in appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

is it possible to remove numbering at figures? I am happy to have numbering in an article, but I would like to remove it from the appendix.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

in the preamble and use `\caption*` where you do not want Figure numbering.

```
\begin{figure}  
\includegraphics{}  
\caption*{Here is a caption}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking that caption* might work, but without the usepackage it sure did not:-) However since it is an article for a jurnal, I had an error that the usepackage is not supported. If I have: \documentclass[epjCONF]{svjour} do you have a solution as well? If not I will just ask them how they want to publish it...